# Python requests posting json containing nan

Tags: python, json, python-requests, http-post, nan

I want to post a send a json object without `nan`. I have an json object containing `nan`.

What will happen if I send that json object containing `nan` using requests's post function?

Do I have to remove them first or will requests replace `nan` with `None`?

Comment: I think it depends on how your json is parsed.

Answer (score 1):

May not be understanding your problem, but it sounds like you want to read data from a json file, and then pass it into `requests.post()`. The `json` module will automatically convert `nan` to `None`.

```
import json

with open(myfile.json) as j:
    my_data=json.load(j)
```

my_data will then be a dictionary you can use however you need.